# Adding totals from two unrelated MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am struggling to work out the correct MySQL syntax to add the result of two queries. The queries draw call records from a table, both generate a single figure result, I need to add them together. I'm sure this can be done with a subquery but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Here are the queries:

```
SELECT SUM(costres) - SUM(costadmin)
FROM call_history, client
WHERE MONTH(start) = 3 AND YEAR(start) = 2012
  AND call_history.client_reseller_id = client.id
  AND client.charging_identifier <> 100000
  AND client.charging_identifier <> 999999;

SELECT SUM(costcl) - SUM(costadmin)
FROM call_history, client
WHERE MONTH(start) = 3 AND YEAR(start) = 2012
 AND call_history.client_reseller_id = client.id
 AND client.charging_identifier = 100000
 AND client.charging_identifier <> 999999;
```

As I said, I know this is simple, but I just can't seem to get my head around subquery syntax in MySQL!

Thanks in advance

George

Comment: Do you want two rows or just one row with two columns?

Comment: Really I just want a single total of the two queries - or an equivalent with one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about -

```
SELECT
    (SUM(IF(client.charging_identifier = 100000, costcl, 0)) - SUM(IF(client.charging_identifier = 100000, costadmin, 0))) +
    (SUM(IF(client.charging_identifier <> 100000, costres, 0)) - SUM(IF(client.charging_identifier <> 100000, costadmin, 0)))
FROM call_history, client
WHERE MONTH(start) = 3 AND YEAR(start) = 2012
AND call_history.client_reseller_id = client.id
AND client.charging_identifier <> 999999;
```

Comment: Very nice, this worked perfectly and was quicker than running two queries. Thanks very much to all who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is flexible in `SELECT` list subqueries, so you can do something like the following, without even needing a `FROM` clause on the main query.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(costres) - SUM(costadmin)
   FROM call_history, client
   WHERE MONTH(start) = 3 AND YEAR(start) = 2012
    AND call_history.client_reseller_id = client.id
    AND client.charging_identifier <> 100000
    AND client.charging_identifier <> 999999
   ) + (
    SELECT SUM(costcl) - SUM(costadmin)
    FROM call_history, client
    WHERE MONTH(start) = 3 AND YEAR(start) = 2012
      AND call_history.client_reseller_id = client.id
      AND client.charging_identifier = 100000
      AND client.charging_identifier <> 999999
   ) AS yourSum;
```

I can't remember if MySQL permits `UNION` inside subqueries. If it does, it is a little nicer to use `SUM()` them across a `UNION`:

```
SELECT SUM(total) as grand_total FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(costres) - SUM(costadmin) AS total
  FROM call_history, client
  WHERE MONTH(start) = 3 AND YEAR(start) = 2012
    AND call_history.client_reseller_id = client.id
    AND client.charging_identifier <> 100000
    AND client.charging_identifier <> 999999
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(costcl) - SUM(costadmin) AS total
  FROM call_history, client
  WHERE MONTH(start) = 3 AND YEAR(start) = 2012
   AND call_history.client_reseller_id = client.id
   AND client.charging_identifier = 100000
   AND client.charging_identifier <> 999999
) unionsub
```

#### Update:

A quick test tells me that you can use `UNION ALL` in a subquery, at least in MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Whoa that was quick! Thanks both. So simple, I knew it would be. Will test and report back.

Comment: Michael, your second query works fine - the first also does but as you said its a little less elegant.